# Getting post data from selected rows in a table

Tags: php, html

I've been trying to think this through, but can't seem to figure out how to get data from only one selected row in a table. I have a table that I am populating with php, lets say it has a name, tn, address in one column. I was thinking of putting a checkbox at the end of the column and having the user check it if the data can be sent to the server. Now, if I do that how do I get the data from that column? I could use javascript to populate the table also, but I'm still stuck with the same problem of how to get the data from the column to update my tables.

```
<?php 
foreach (defaultPay() as $key => $values):
  foreach ($values as $value):?>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="number"></label><input type="text" id="number" name="empNum" value="<?= $value['empNum']; ?>">
      </td>
      <td>
        <label for="name"></label><input type="text" id="name" name="empName" value="<?= $value['empName']; ?>">
      </td>
      <td>
        <label for="stdHrs"></label><input type="text" step="any" id="stdHrs" name="stdHrs" value="<?= $value['unitRate']; ?>">
      </td>
      <td>
        <label for="uniRate"></label><input type="text" step="any" id="uniRate" name="uniRate" value="<?= $value['rate']; ?>">
      </td>
      <td>
        <label for="salRate"></label><input type="text" step="any" id="salRate" name="salRate" value="<?= $value['salary']; ?>">
      </td>
      <td>
        <label for="gross"></label><input type="text" step="any" id="gross" name="gross" value="<?= $value['gross']; ?>">
     </td>
   </tr>
  <?php }
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are populating the table from some kind of php array. If you don't have unique identifier, each element have index in array. You could use that index and set it as checkbox value.

For example:

`<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $index; ?>" />`

where `$index` is unique table index. After form submition you will have selected indexes of the table. Remember to keep te table order the same.

Comment: I am using a php array and populating like this:  `<td><label for="salRate"></label><input type="text" step="any" id="salRate" name="salRate" value="<?= $value['salary']; ?>"></td>`

Comment: Please provide full code with the loop part (foreach, for, while etc.)

Comment: As I can see in the edited part of question, you could use `$key` for your index.

Answer (score 0):

If only one row will be selected by the user a button within a form will do.  Forms and hidden input does not affect page rendering.  Just make the form CSS display:inline; The whole form can be put in one small `<td>` table element regardless of how much data you want to store in multiple `<input type="hidden"/>` tags.

```
'<tr><td><form action="save.php" method="post" ><input type="hidden" name="id" value="1234" /><input type="hidden" name="col1" value="' . $row[1] . '" /><input type="hidden" name="col2" value="' . $row[2] . '" /> <button type="submit">Save</button></form></td><td>Text describing the row</td></tr>';
```

The first column in the table has a "Save" button which submits the data.